# Is there a command that can be moved to a folder by file name in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I want to read the file name with the command and automatically move it to the folder with the same name. What should I do?

example:

before processing

[image]

after processing

[image]

If I have files and folders with the same name, I want to move them to a folder with the same name.

What should I do? Do I have a cmd command?

Comment: .bat is not really suitable for pattern matching, maybe powershell or a script like node.js or python or even php

Comment: Thank you.What are the ways to use a powershell ?

Comment: @전준휘 http://powershelltutorial.net/

Comment: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208326/12343998) can easily be adapted to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will provide both a solution to this exact question, and an alternative that I would suggest to handle this situation.

**==========**
**~ Solution ~**
**==========**

- Copy/Paste the code below into an empty file, save, and execute.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b *.xlsx') do (
  if not "%%a_%%b"=="%~nx0" (
    if not exist %%a mkdir %%a
    move "%%a_%%b" "%%a\"
  )
)
```

- You can change the "*.xlsx" to any other file extension, or change to "*.*" to work with ANY file extension.
- Keep in mind though, this ONLY works with filenames that are formatted like the way you mentioned in your question.

**===================**
**~ Alternative Solution~**
**===================**

I would suggest the Shell Extension "Files 2 Folder" as an alternative. I came across a situation where I needed something similar to what you're asking a couple years ago, and this ended up working out great.

https://www.dcmembers.com/skwire/download/files-2-folder/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I Want it result. Can I ask you one more question?
If there is no folder that matches the file, can you automatically create the folder and move the file?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using regex in vbscript with a batch file :

```bat
@echo off & color 0A
Title Extract Title using Regex in vbscript

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.xlsx') do (
    Call :Extract_Title "%%a" Title
    If Defined Title (
        If Not Exist "!Title!\" MkDir "!Title!\"
        Move /-Y "%%a" "!Title!\"
    )
)

Pause & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Extract_Title <InputFile> <Title to be Set>
>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" (
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Extract_Title(Data^)
    echo Function Extract_Title(Data^)
    echo    Data = Wscript.Arguments(0^) 
    echo    Set re = New RegExp 
    echo    re.Global = True 
    echo    re.IgnoreCase = True  
    echo    re.Pattern = "(\S+|\S.+)_" 
    echo    For Each Match in re.Execute(Data^) 
    echo        Title = Match.SubMatches(0^) 
    echo    Next
    echo    Extract_Title = Title
    echo End Function
)
@for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"') do set "%2=%%A"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```